# Sharepoint 2013 Retrieving values from list and autopopulate input fields using javascript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, auto-populate

I have this list [image]

And I have this form [image]

Which has to be autopopulated when the user input the Employee ID from the list.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approaches to fulfill your requirements:

1. To retrieve list data from SharePoint 2013 list, you can use SharePoint REST API.
2. To autopopulate the data from list, you can use **datalist** in html5.

**Steps**:

1. First retrieve all list items from SharePoint List using REST API.
2. Create arrays of options for each field on your form to autopopulate from data result you will get from REST.
3. Append those arrays of options to each field on your form using datalist tag.

Sources:

1. [Retrieve SharePoint List Items Using Rest API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-rest-api).
2. [HTML5 Datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp).
3. [Html datalist values from array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929356/html-datalist-values-from-array-in-javascript).

Comment: Have you tried this?